# Rails 4.2: repopulating a dynamically populated thing after form validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails 4.2 app.  On my "New document" form, I have a select and a div containing a collection_check_boxes.  When the user changes the value of the select, I use AJAX to repopulate the div containing the checkboxes so that the available checkboxes change depending on what item is selected in the select menu.  The AJAX is working fine.

Here is the Javascript that detects when the select changes:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#document_project_id', function(event) {
    $.ajax('/populate_document_reviewer_list', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        project_id: $("#document_project_id option:selected").val(),
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My problem is that if something in the form fails validation, the form with errors is displayed. In this re-displayed form, the user's selection for the select is pre-populated, but the div containing the checkboxes displays the default choices because the onchange on the select did not fire so my AJAX to show the correct checkboxes is not called.

My question is, how can I display the correct checkboxes after a form validation error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

In my form, I added a conditional to check whether there were any errors.  If there are errors, I populate the checkbox div manually based on the selected item in the select.  If there are no errors, I display the default text.

```
<% if @doc.errors.any? %>
  <% if @doc.project.is_secret? %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:reviewer_ids, @doc.project.disclosed_users.order(:first_name, :last_name), :id, :name_with_job_title) do |b| %>
      <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %><br>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:reviewer_ids, User.order(:first_name, :last_name), :id, :name_with_job_title) do |b| %>
      <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %><br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  Select a project to see reviewers.
<% end %>
```